# Cross-compile GCC for x86_64-w64-mingw32 target

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling, glibc, libc

I would like to cross-compile GCC 6.3.0 for x86_64-w64-mingw32 target on Ubuntu 16.04.
I'm following the below steps:

0. **Get the source files**:

   $ wget "http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/mingw-w64-v5.0.1.tar.bz2"

   $ wget  "https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.27.tar.gz"

   $ wget "https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2"
1. **Compile binutils-2.27 with**:

   $ ./configure --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/home/user/gcc_mingw64/build --with-sysroot=/home/user/gcc_mingw64/build

   $ make

   $ make install
2. **Compile mingw-w64-v5**:

   $ mkdir build-headers

   $ cd build-headers/

   $ ../mingw-w64-headers/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/home/user/gcc_mingw64/build/x86_64-w64-mingw32

   $ make

   $ make install
3. **Create soft link to lib**:

   $ ln -s /home/user/gcc_mingw64/build/x86_64-w64-mingw32 mingw

   $ ln -s /home/user/gcc_mingw64/build/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib lib64
4. **Compile gcc-6.3.0**:

   $ ./contrib/download_prerequisites

   $ mkdir build_gcc

   $ cd build_gcc

   $ ../configure --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --disable-shared --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-ld=/home/user/gcc_mingw64/build/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --with-as=/home/user/gcc_mingw64/build/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --prefix=/home/user/gcc_mingw64/build --with-sysroot=/home/user/gcc_mingw64/build

   $ make

   $ make install

The gcc compilation throw the following error:

```
checking for ld that supports -Wl,--gc-sections... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:11457: recipe for target 'configure-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
```

Any clue on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure but a guess is that it's trying to use the mingw toolchain to build gcc instead of the ubuntu one. GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES probably refers to a prior part of configure, which failed?

Comment: Why do you cross-compile it? Find a prebuilt one, there are plenty.